# Make marker invisible in google maps

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps and some asp controls like checkboxlist and dropdownlist.
Initially map is populated with some markers.
I want to hide some of the markers in the map if checkboxlist value changed (selected index changed).
Toggling Show and Hide of markers on selected index changed is not working as it triggering postback.

please help me to get this done.

Thanking you,

AGM RAJA

Answer (score 0):

When you populate your initial map, how are you keeping track of those added markers? Google Maps has no way to query for them later, and they aren't added to the DOM as to pick them using a css selector.

You might want to push each added marker to a list, to retrieve them later by their keyname.

```
     var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
      zoom: 8,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
        mapOptions);
    var googlemarkers={};

    googlemarkers['mynewmarker']=new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644), map:map});
```

And then, when you unselect a checkbox

```
var mymarker=googlemarkers['mynewmarker'];
mymarker.setMap(null);
```

Comment: Hi amenadiel,im using array to store the marker initially created.
but that is not the issue. when unchecking a checkbox,map disappeared.
because i have set the autopostback as true to the checkboxlist.

Comment: I believe that's some propietary behavior or asp.net. I wonder, however, how are you linking a particular control checkbox to a given marker?